# Python (Portable 2.5) subprocess report problem "WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified"

Tags: python, subprocess, portability, popen

I am using python and the codes are all worked well with non-portable version. Since I need to run the program on some computer that does not belong to me, which does not have installed python or such option available.
I use portable python instead. However the codes previously works well now report error"WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified". I checked it on my computer. It works smoothly without the above error. Anybody can give a clue?

The cmd I am using is :

p = subprocess.Popen(self.cmdStr, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=file)

I am redirecting the stderr to a file I specified.

I also googled online. There seems to have an issue of "subprocess PATH semantics and portability". I am not sure whether this is the reason. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, the problem is in the cmdStr variable. You must use absolute paths, or else have the *user the process is running under* have an appropriately setup PATH system variable. That or you have shell=False, which can cause problems in the subprocess module. Check the documentation for issues concerning paths etc.

Comment: I am using the absolute paths.

Comment: as well as the output stderr file. I also specified the absolute path. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Mua Alright, does my.exe exist on the computer that doesn't belong to you? I don't think that will be packaged into your program by portable python.

Comment: Sorry, found the bug. The exe is in another folder on other's computer. So now there is no issue. ;). Thank you. Spencer.

Answer (score 0):

Can 'cmd /c cmdstr' run correctly on windows?

Answer (score 0):

subprocess.Popen(r"C:\Python27\python.exe",shell=True) can work correctly.